# Hiding the second column values by default and OnClick of first column value it Shows

Tags: php, jquery, codeigniter

I need to hide the second column values which are dynamically coming from the database of first and second column both. all i do is that what i load the page or refresh the second column values should be invisible/hide. and as soon as i click on 1st column any of the options it shows the second column values.

Here is some code. which i have tried using jQuery but the thing which i want is unable to reach. actually it shows both column values when i click on 1st one it hide the second :/.
Someone can help me out :/. I am a bit confused. Thanks for any help !!

**Script for column 1:**

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        var link = "<?php echo base_url(); ?>";
        $('#cat_1').click(function(){
            var cat_1 = alert($(this).val());
            $.post(link + 'admin/admin_cat/category/cat_level_2' , {cat_1:cat_1}, function(data)
            {
                $('#cat_3').html('');
                $('#cat_4').html('');
                $('#cat_2').html('');
            });
        });
    });
    </script>
```

**Script for column 2 :**

```
<script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            var link = "<?php echo base_url(); ?>";
            $('#cat_2').click(function(){
                var cat_2 = alert($(this).val());
                $.post(link + 'admin/admin_cat/category/cat_level_3' , {cat_2:cat_2}, function(data)
                {
                    $('#cat_3').html('');
                    $('#cat_4').html('');
                });
            });
        });
    </script>
```

**HTML/PHP :**

```
<div class="category-col">
<select size="15" name="cat_1" id="cat_1">
    <?php foreach ($dropdown as  $cat_1) ?>
    <?php  { ?>
        <option
            value=" <?php echo form_dropdown('cat_level', $dropdown);?> ">
        </option>
    <?php  } ?>
</select>
</div>

<div class="category-col">
<select size="15" name='cat_2' id='cat_2' >

    <?php if(isset($cat_level_2) && $cat_level_2 != false){ ;?>
        <?php foreach ($cat_level_2 as  $cat_2)  {?>
            <option value="">
                <?php echo $cat_2; ?>
            </option>
        <?php } }?>
</select>
</div>
```

Comment: Mix of PHP, HTML and JS, duplicating JS code (click event handlers), `<script>` inside `<select>` - well, it's all more than confusing.

Comment: `var cat_1 = alert($(this).val());` is incorrect, it has to be `var cat_1 = $(this).val();`. If `<select>` with empty inner HTML is hidden in your browser, try to stay one default `<option>` in it. Something like `$('#cat_2').html('<option></option>');` I also don't see that you use received `data` anywhere.